# BottomSheetDialog background blinking

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

[`BottomSheetDialog`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetDialog)'s background is blinking when switching between apps. What am I doing wrong ?

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.btn1).setOnClickListener(v -> {
            BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(MainActivity.this);
            bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(R.layout.content);
            bottomSheetDialog.show();
        });
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**content.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:background="#F00" />
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.holtaf.testandroidapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My `appcompat` version is **27.1.1**.

[image]

Comment: Can you post your complete code of the activity and its xml

Comment: OnResume your bottom sheet is getting refreshed. You might want to check that.

Comment: @RoyalGriffin I have included my activity_main.xml also. This is the whole code I'm using right now.

Comment: I will investigate more, but my first impression is BottomSheetDialog class redraw the layout while pausing and starting. Time which is taken while pausing and starting it because of animation which BottomSheetDialog is having.

Comment: have you put some code in onResume of your activity, if not then try to put some buttons etc inside bottomsheet and remove the red color, then see what happens

Comment: @AbdulAziz I have posted MainActivity as it is and adding buttons to bottom sheet or removing the red color doesn't have any effects, it's still buggy.

Comment: @holtaf I think it's bug of android OS. Because if you try this with the system dialog you will get this same effect. Even i saw it on Google Play Music app also.

Answer (score 9):

The main reason for the flickering is due to the default styling of the `BottomSheetDialog` which defines a default [animation](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/design/res/values/styles.xml#L128) and the [dim](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_support/blob/592b1d9ca451ee6a4d0920b2e40827cd8a71520f/v7/appcompat/res/values/themes_base.xml#L490) behavior.

We can resolve the above issue by defining a custom theme using `bottomSheetDialogTheme` which in turn:

1. Disables the default window animation for the BottomSheet by setting  [windowAnimationStyle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowAnimationStyle) to `@null`.
2. Sets the [backgroundDimEnabled](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#backgroundDimEnabled) attribute to `false`.

Example:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/AppTheme.BottomSheetDialog</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.BottomSheetDialog" parent="Theme.Design.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>

    <!-- optional -->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">#99323232</item> 
</style>
```

Comment: There is also a `Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog`.

Comment: This is not an acceptable solution. It disables both the dimming and the scrolling animation of the dialog, basically rendering it useless.

Comment: android:backgroundDimEnabled is also optional, window animation is the key

Comment: excellent. thank you

Answer (score -1):

Use Coordinate layout instead of constraint layout, and define bottomsheet layout in xml like below

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

         <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

         <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

               <include layout="@layout/layout_bottom_sheet" />
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In Java Class Use like this.

```
    private BottomSheetBehavior mBottomSheetBehavior;
    private View bottomSheet;
    private isBottomSheetExpand = false;
    ...
    btn1.setOnClickListner(new View.OncliView.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(isBottomSheetExpand){
                openBottomSheet();
            }else{
                closeBottomSheet();
            }
        }
    });
    ...
    public void closeBottomSheet() {
       if (mBottomSheetBehavior.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
            mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
            isBottomSheetExpand = false;
        }
    }

    public void openBottomSheet() {
        if (mBottomSheetBehavior.getState() != BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
            mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
            isBottomSheetExpand = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works Ok but there are problems with it. It does not have a background dim, and it's affected by software keyboard (when keyboard is shown it jumps up).

Comment: Add this `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in `AndroidManifest.xml` file it will solve keyboard problem

Comment: For dim background apply `android:background="@null"` to `NestedScrollView` and give `layout_bottom_sheet` transparency color it will work.

Comment: It will throw an error "The view is not a child of CoordinatorLayout" because view is inside nested scroll view

Answer (score -1):

According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetBehavior) the setPeekHeight method is responsible for the pop up behavior. Using the

```
bottomSheet.setState(STATE_HIDDEN) should do the trick.
```

Comment: This is not related to the issue.