# Android BottomSheetDialogFragment blinking

Tags: android, kotlin, bottom-sheet, android-bottomsheetdialog, bottomsheetdialogfragment

I startActivity from BottomSheetDialogFragment.

But when I finish the Activity, the BottomSheetDialogFragment is blinking.

My case is like this one [BottomSheetDialog background blinking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51097844/bottomsheetdialog-background-blinking)

But there is no solution.

[Here is my screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkao9.jpg)

The code is simple and basic.

MainActivity.class

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val bottomSheetFragment = BottomSheetFragment()

        button.setOnClickListener {

            bottomSheetFragment.show(supportFragmentManager, "")
        }
    }
}
```

BottomSheetFragment.class

```
class BottomSheetFragment: BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottom_sheet, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        button.setOnClickListener {

            startActivity(Intent(context!!, Test2Activity::class.java))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dismiss your bottomsheet ehen you launch activity

Comment: @Vikas I don't want to dismiss it. I want to see the bottomSheet Immediately when activity finish.

Answer (score 0):

Your Bottom sheet is not Blinking. its the effect of activity when you get back to MainActivity.
in your MainActivity Please implement overridePendingTransition before onCreate()

`overridePendingTransition(0,0)` // due to this default effect will remove

Comment: I add `    override fun overridePendingTransition(enterAnim: Int, exitAnim: Int) {
        overridePendingTransition(0,0)
    }` in `MainActivity`, but not works.